# How to retrieve record match memberID, month and year from sql database

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, database, datatable

This might be a stupid question but i failed to do through tutorial found online,
i got a table call tblPOS
inside got item,quantity,total,memberid,posdate
now i gonna retrieve match information for report end of the month
what the form do is ask a member id , and month + year he want to see

May i know how could i find the match record first check member id,
then extract month and year from tblPOS of posdate
finally get ONLY record match month and year request for specific member ?

Thx in advance =D

Comment: you question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, however this query might get you started:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPOS
WHERE MemberID = {memberID}
  AND posdate >= '2011-02-01' AND postdate < '2011-03-01'
```

You can use the sql `DATEPART()` function, however it is better to format the query with the date range, that way indexes can be used.

Comment: sorry for unclear XD how if i want to extract the month and year ? Thx =D

Comment: @spencer-lim use `SELECT MONTH(posdate), YEAR(posdate)`

Comment: Thx =D you helped me a lot and this is the last problem in my assignment XD